# r bookdown::pdf_book fails to parse book.bib file with natbib

Tags: r, knitr, tex, bookdown

we are trying to write a bookdown publication hosted at https://github.com/guilhermejacob/context/

i've tried removing different entries from my `book.bib` and each time get the error below.  the `bookdown::tufte_html_book` command works without issue, only the `bookdown::pdf_book` dies for me despite what appears to be nothing wrong with my `book.bib` citation file?

https://github.com/guilhermejacob/context/blob/master/book.bib

i've googled around and all of the tex questions point to things like missing `author=` or `year=` or `title=` tags while each of my entries has all of them.

i get the same error when i have an empty book.bib file, so something else in the folder must be configured improperly?  but i have no idea where to look because the natbib seems to have a issue with book.bib?  i'd appreciate any pointers about what to try..thanks

```
Latexmk, John Collins, 5 Sep. 2016. Version 4.48
! Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations.

Error: Failed to compile context.tex. See context.log for more info.
In addition: Warning messages:
1: running command '"C:\Users\AnthonyD\AppData\Local\Programs\MIKTEX~1.9\miktex\bin\latexmk.exe" -v' had status 1 
2: The LaTeX package latexmk was not correctly installed. 
3: running command '"C:\Users\AnthonyD\AppData\Local\Programs\MIKTEX~1.9\miktex\bin\latexmk.exe" -v' had status 1 
4: running command '"xelatex" -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode "context.tex"' had status 1 
Execution halted
```

Answer (score 0):

i deleted the `.aux` file as suggested here.  solved the problem.  no clue why.

http://arhetoric.blogspot.com/2011/10/natlibs-usage-fixing-some-errors.html?showComment=1338381839988